# solve error : "Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1"

Tags: objective-c, ios4

In my application I have integrate Three20 Library and Restkit framework, after this I am Build the code the error was generated 
the error is :

```
     `"Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1"`
```

and the error description is

```
  ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RKJSONParser in /Users/pratikkanada/Desktop/Zipogo/Zipongo - working     
  version/RestKit/Build/Release-iphonesimulator/libRestKitJSONParserYAJL.a(RKJSONParser+YAJL.o) and 
  /Users/pratikkanada/Desktop/Zipogo/Zipongo - working version/RestKit/Build/Release-
  iphonesimulator/libRestKitJSONParserSBJSON.a(RKJSONParser+SBJSON.o)
```

so, pls tell me how to solve this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have added that lib two times.

Please search `libRestKitJSONParserSBJSON.a` and `(RKJSONParser+SBJSON.o)` in entire code and you may found one of these added two times.

Simply solution is remove any one of two same files.